# Is this some type of sweet pea?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, sweet-pea

This plant was a gift and the flower keeps coming back. Is it a sweet pea? I can’t be sure because the leaves don’t look like sweet pea, at [image]least that I know of. It is so pretty.

Answer (score 3):

Your plant is *Cyclamen persicum*, also known as florist cyclamen. Yours isn't looking too healthy judging by the foliage, but perhaps it coming up for dormancy - they tend to flower during winter and early spring, then die down and return later on. There are other types of cyclamen which can be grown outdoors, but this one is really a houseplant, and won't  tolerate low temperatures, although it also does not like temperatures much above 20 deg C either. Care instructions here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/cyclamen/cyclamen-care.htm

Comment: Oh, wow- thanks so much! I will have to give it some TLC.